# Message not found in user mailbox while working on microsoft graph explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Auto Remediation not happening. `Error :- message not present in User's mailbox` .

**Scenario**:
While working on microsoft graph explorer and sending mail with attachment the outlook is not able to auto remediate the message and while checking the url on graph explorer i am not getting any value associated with it and also i am getting the error like the message is not there in the user mailbox.

The Attachment name which I am using are double byte Chinese characters (发送邮.xml)

Instead of this if I am using attachment name like this (for e.g 送邮.xml) then it is working as expected and the mail is successfully getting remediated.

Is there any bit size limit of attachment names in graph explorer because of which it is not taking that attachment name(发送邮.xml) whereas it is working fine with (送邮.xml)

Please help me with this.

Comment: I have tried giving the payload this way and used the same name that didn't work for you. But I was able to success send mail using Graph Explorer.

        "attachments": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                "name": "发送邮.xml",
                "contentType": "text/plain",
                "contentBytes": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
            }

Comment: Editing tags since I don't believe this is related to the Graph Education APIs. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Are you still looking for help?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried giving the payload this way and used the same name that didn't work for you. But I was able to success send mail using Graph Explorer.

```
"attachments": [ 
                 { 
                     "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment", 
                     "name": "发送邮.xml", 
                     "contentType": "text/plain", 
                     "contentBytes": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh" 
                 }
               ]
```